# Italian number words from eleven to nineteen - history of a bizarre, inconsistent construction

Tags: history, numbers, etymology

Let's count in Latin from one to twenty:

> ūnus/ūna/ūnum, duo/duae/duo, trēs/tria, quattuor, quīnque, sex, septem, octō, novem, decem,
>
> ūndecim, duodecim, tredecim, quattuordecim, quīndecim, sēdecim, septendecim, duodēvīgintī, ūndēvīgintī, vīgintī

As pointed out by symbiotech, "octodecim" and "novemdecim" were also used in Latin, but they didn't survive. On the other hand, as pointed out by martina, "[dĕcem (et) sĕptem](http://www.garzantilinguistica.it/ricerca/?q=diciassette)" was also a common form for "septemdĕcim".

In Attic Greek it was:

> ΕΙΣ/ΜΙΑ/ΕΝ (heis/mia/en), ΔΥΟ (dúō), ΤΡΕΙΣ/ΤΡΙΑ (treis/tria), ΤΕΤΤΑΡΕΣ/ΤΕΤΤΑΡΑ (téttares/téttara), ΠΕΝΤΕ (pénte), ΕΞ (héx), ΕΠΤΑ (heptá), ΟΚΤΩ (oktṓ), ΕΝΝΕΑ (ennéa), ΔΕΚΑ (déka),
>
> ΕΝΔΕΚΑ (héndeka), ΔΩΔΕΚΑ (dódeka), ΤΡΕΙΣΚΑΙΔΕΚΑ (treiskaídeka), ΤΕΤΤΑΡΕΣ ΚΑΙ ΔΕΚΑ (téttares kaì déka), ΠΕΝΤΕΚΑΙΔΕΚΑ (pentekaídeka), ΕΚΚΑΙΔΕΚΑ (hekkaídeka), ΕΠΤΑΚΑΙΔΕΚΑ (heptakaídeka), ΟΚΤΩΚΑΙΔΕΚΑ (oktōkaídeka), ΕΝΝΕΑΚΑΙΔΕΚΑ (enneakaídeka), ΕΙΚΟΣΙ(Ν) (eíkosi(n))

Now let's count in Italian

> uno, due, tre, quattro, cinque, sei, sette, otto, nove, dieci,
>
> undici, dodici, tredici, quattordici, quindici, sedici, diciassette,
> diciotto, diciannove, venti.

But numbers from eleven to twenty could also have been, just hypothetically of course (adding accents for clarity's sake):

> diciùno, diciaddùe, diciattré, diciacquàttro, diciaccìnque, diciassèi, diciassètte, diciòtto, diciannòve, vénti

or

> undici, dodici, tredici, quattordici, quindici, sedici, settèndici, ottòdici, novèndici, venti.

In Spanish it is:

> uno, dos, tres, cuatro, cinco, seis, siete, ocho, nueve, diez,
>
> once, doce, trece, catorce, quince, dieciseis, diecisiete, dieciocho, diecinueve, veinte

In Portuguese:

> um, dois, três, quarto, cinco, seis, sete, oito, nove, dez,
>
> onze, doze, treze, catorze, quinze, dezasseis, dezassete, dezoito, dezanove, vinte

In French:

> un, deux,trois, quatre, cinq, six, sept, huit, neuf, dix,
>
> onze, douze, treize, quatorze, quinze, seize, dix-sept, dix-huit, dix-neuf, vingt

Following martina's hint here are the number words from one to twenty in Romanian:

> unu, doi, trei, patru, cinci, şase, şapte, opt, nouă, zece,
>
> unsprezece, doisprezece, treisprezece, paisprezece, cincisprezece, şaisprezece, şaptesprezece, optsprezece, nouăsprezece, douăzeci

I find Latin, Italian, Spanish, Portuguese and French constructions for number words bizarre and inconsistent (whereas in Romanian it seems they are perfectly consistent - thanks martina for her hint - as well as in Ancient Greek). Is there any academic work on the history of number words in Latin/Italian/Spanish/Portuguese/French where the origin of number words from eleven to nineteen is tracked down, documented, explained, discussed?